# Custom AWT Title Window

Tags: java, awt

I am new to AWT and I have been given a Photoshop mock up. I have to design a mock up Window based in AWT

Currently, I am stuck at Title Bar design.The Title Window looks like this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziCgD.png

Please let me know how can I accomplish this using AWT.
I am aware that I need to use setUndecorated(true) to get rid of default Title Window, but then I have no idea about how can I implement the one that is shown in the image.

I am just looking for a direction.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: First of all I would rethink if that needs to be done in AWT and consider Swing instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a JPanel (if your working with Swing, see Panel in AWT) with a gradient background. I don't really know AWT but in Swing, do the following:

- set the JPanel layout to BorderLayout,
- add a JLabel as the centered component for the title (with the icon),
- add a JLabel with just the cross icon for the "close" button as the right component
- add the whole panel to the top of your window (using a BorderLayout for your window pane for instance)

Comment: Hi.thanks for the answer.But just wanted to know is not possible to modify the default Title Bar and acheive the same ?

Comment: It is only possible for swing JFrame. You said that you must use AWT, so @Aurélien Ribon gave you the solution.

Comment: OKies..but then is it possible to Drag the window using the Title Bar build in Panel ?

Comment: Yes, add a MouseMotionListener to the panel and in the mouseDragged event, call the setLocation() method of the whole frame. Sometimes you have to do things yourself, but it doesn't mean that it is impossible.